# Website with javascript doesn't work in IE9 but in IE9's compatibility mode - how to force compatibility view?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, bxslider

I know that there already is a question like this: [Force IE9 into browser compatibility view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519645/force-ie9-into-browser-compatibility-view)

But since adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

to the the head section and reloading the page with ctrl+F5 didn't help there must be another way.

On my website is also a bxslider and according to this: [bxslider not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556702/bxslider-not-working-in-ie9) I replaced the  elements (which had empty href attribute) with  tags - still not effect. The images of the slider are displayed in full size one below the other. After activating compatibility mode the site works perfect.

I don't wanna rebuild my application from the scratch so what could I do to force the compatibility-view? Or is there at least a good free debugging tool for that? I downloaded the firefox addon IE Tab which has a debugbar but to use it you have to buy a premium version. I just don't know what is causing the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the error: [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

So frustrating and so simple. It was caused by the console.logs in the script. Without them it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code at the start of your JS (I use it in all my projects) https://gist.githubusercontent.com/elijahmanor/7884984/raw/console-monkey-patch.js it will override the console.log function so you avoid errors in IE but still get logging in modern browsers like chrome.